# Contradictory answers for finding the expected number of samples to get $X > X_0$ where $X, X_0 \in \{0, 1\}$ with equal probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm discussing this problem with a friend, and we're getting contradictory answers.

Consider $X_0$ to take on values $\in \{0, 1\}$ (the number of values and their magnitudes aren't really important, so these values could be anything or any number of values) with equal probability of $0.5$.

Define $N$ to be the minimum number of samples you need to draw (with replacement) from $\{0, 1\}$. What is $E[N]$?

My approach is based on law of total expectation:

$$
E[N] = \sum_{k\in\{0, 1\}} E[N | X_0 = k] P(X_0 = k) \\
= E[N | X_0 = 0] P(X_0 = 0) + E[N | X_0 = 1] P(X_0 = 1) \\
= 2 * 0.5 + \infty*0.5 = \infty
$$

This is controlled completely by $E[N | X_0 = 1]$, which is infinity because we can never draw a value greater than 1.

My friend's approach:

View $N$ to be a geometric random variable for the number of samples to get a value greater than $X_0$. Then

$$
E[N] = \frac{1}{P(X > X_0)} \\
P(X > X_0) = P(X > X_0 | X_0 = 1)P(X_0 = 1) + P(X > X_0 | X_0 = 0)P(X_0 = 0) \\
= 0 * 1 + 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25 \\
E[N] = 4
$$

His approach kind of doesn't make sense to me. I'm not sure if you can define a geometric random variable to be that way, i.e., the number of samples it takes to get a value greater than a RANDOM VARIABLE. Can a geometric RV be legitimately defined this way?

I think the $E[N] = \frac{1}{P(X > X_0)}$ is problematic, but I don't know what is theoretically wrong with it, but I think $\frac{1}{P(X > X_0)}$ is actually a random variable?

My friend came up with a second approach, which matches his first approach.
$$
E[N] = \sum_{k \in \{0,1\}} E[N |  X_0 = k]P(X_0 = k) \\
E[N |  X_0 = k] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i P(X_i > k) \prod_{j=1}^{i - 1} P(X_j \leq k) \\
E[N |  X_0 = 1] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i P(X_i > 1) \prod_{j=1}^{i - 1} P(X_j \leq 1) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i * 0.5^1 = 2 \\
E[N |  X_0 = 2] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i P(X_i > 2) \prod_{j=1}^{i - 1} P(X_j \leq 1) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0 = 0 \\
\therefore E[N] = 2
$$

The followup question was what if we're now sampling $X_0$ and all the other samples from continuous $U(0, 1)$. My answer wouldn't change, and his would be some finite value. I am hesitant to say that my answer would still be infinity because I know the probability of realizing a specific value in a continuous distribution is zero, so technically shouldn't $X_0$ have a zero probability of reaching $1.0$, which would seem to then bound the $E[N]$.

Comment: Your friend is asking the following question: suppose that each day, two numbers $X^t, X_0^t$ are drawn independently of the past, and of each other, uniformly from $\{0,1\}$. How many days do you need to wait until $X^t > X_0^t$ occurs? You are asking the following question: suppose that on the $0$th day, a value $X_0$ was picked uniformly from $\{0,1\}$. Now, each day, a number $X^t$ is drawn independently of the past and uniformly from $\{0,1\}$. How many days do you have to wait until $X^t> X_0$ occurs?

Comment: Both are reasonable questions. You should mutually decide which one captures the setting you wanted to investigate to begin with.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Ah based on your first comment, then I believe it should be my question that we're trying to answer. The original question is actually find $E[\alpha]$ where $\alpha = \inf\{k > 0 : X_k > X_0\}$ and $\{ X_i \}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ are IID continuous.

Comment: Yup, that is your question (and I guess I should have said answering instead of asking in the first comment). For your follow up - as you noted, the finite argument doesn't hold because the probability of $X_0$ reaching the extreme value is $0$. To actually compute this stuff, notice that given $X_0$, the law of $N$ is easy to figure out (it's just geometric). Use this to compute the conditional expectation given $X_0$, and then total probability to figure out the mean of $N$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 But how do you do the follow up when it's a continuous distribution? Are you suggesting I should sum over an infinite number of terms or take the integral? $E[N] = \int_0^1 E[N | X_0 = x] f(x) dx =  \int_0^1 E[N | X_0 = x] dx$?

Comment: Yeah, precisely. Formally the way this is working is that $\mathbb{E}[N|X_0]$ is some function of $X_0$, and you're just taking its expectation.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Ahhh so is $E[N | X_0 = x] = 1/(1 - x)$ assuming $X \sim U(0 ,1)$?

Comment: Yup, you're right. BTW I'd encourage you to write an answer if you feel like you've gotten a grasp of the problem. This a) lets someone run an eye over your argument, b) leaves a detailed record for someone that might have a similar question in the future, and c) resolves the question within the MSE system.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that in a sec. For this particular example with $X \sim U(0,1)$, we get $E[N] = \infty$. But the original problem didn't actually specific what the continuous distribution is, so I'm wondering if infinity is actually the case in general for continuous distributions of any sort. I just edited in another approach my friend just came up with. Do you mind checking what what's wrong with that? It gives the same answer as his first approach, and it looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Yes, it is, at least if the distributions have a density (don't know if it holds more generally). As a hint for showing this - try to express $\mathbb{E}[N|X_0]$ in terms of the cdf. As for your friend's second argument - why is it that when $X_0$ hits the extreme value, you expect to exceed it in $0$ draws? In fact since $N$ is at least $1$ no matter what (you have to make at least one draw), it doesn't make sense for $\mathbb{E}[N|X_0=x]$ to be $0$. This at least shows there's an error. The origin seems to be that your friend assumes that $N$ is always finite - this is not the case.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Right, I agree with that it doesn't make sense for it to be 0 draws. We were looking at his formula, and I couldn't figure out what was wrong with it. The expression he wrote looks correct to me, but obviuosly the result of zero cannot be right. What part of the expression do you believe he made the assumption that $N$ is always finite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120384/discussion-between-stochasticboy321-and-student010101).